# How to sign in and sign out from Google within one Activity

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm beginner in Java and Android programming. I'm trying to create Login system with Google on my app. What I want to do is to switch sign in and sign out button in an activity. However, once I sign in successfully, I can never sign out from Google. Even if I uninstalled the app, I couldn't sign out.

Here is my code.

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    mSignOutButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
    mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signOut();
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // Check for existing Google Sign In account, if the user is already signed in
    // the GoogleSignInAccount will be non-null.
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    updateUI(account);
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent intent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
}


private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String idToken = account.getIdToken();

        // Send the token to the API endpoint and validate


        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        updateUI(null);
    }
}


private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {
    if (signInAccount != null) {
        mSignInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSignOutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mSignInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSignOutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

How can I sign out correctly and update the UI within one activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating your code based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect) on how to sign out and disconnect.
this will wait until the user is signed out from the server and updates the app UI.

```
private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Seems like it doesn't work unless I set `addCompleteListener`. I could sign out when I set this.